# A [choice] has been made to remove this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There are 541 questions tagged [choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/choice), and more importantly than having no experts or being ambiguous, the tag seems to be an excellent fit for questions trying to choose between [styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340624/do-you-leave-parentheses-in-or-out-in-ruby), [frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399210/what-is-your-favorite-gwt-mvp-framework) or [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622917/learning-a-web-language). Is burninating this tag worth the effort?

Comment: It certainly seems like a possibility that many questions tagged with choice could be opinion based.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/choice) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about the Java class `java.awt.Choice` should also have the [awt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awt) tag
- Questions about the batch command can be tagged [batch-choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-choice) (not yet created at the time of writing)
- Questions about random choices can be tagged [random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random)

  - Other (specific) tags about types of random selections include [combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combinations) and [permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permutation)

## Progress:

The [choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/choice) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=choice),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bchoice%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bchoice%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bchoice%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bchoice%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=280351)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/choice) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/choice) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/choice) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: What about `random.choice` - new tag?

Comment: @dan1st Not entirely convinced it's needed. Tags for individual functions are fairly rare as well

Comment: `random.choice` (or the concept of choosing one of different options) exists in many programming languages (and there are quite a few questions about it)

Comment: @dan1st Isn't that effectively [tag:random] with extra steps?

Comment: Yes, it is essentially that.

Answer (score 15):

As slugster [already pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280363/), there are some valid uses of "choice". In addition to their example of a DOS command, there is also [java.awt.Choice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html), an old GUI component.

I suggest we disambiguate the tag first, then burninate it.

Comment: Note that for all intents and purposes, disambiguation followed by a burnination is a burnination. All questions (worth preserving; i.e. the non-closeable ones) worth retagging get retagged during a burnination, including to new disambiguation targets when necessary

Answer (score 3):

Initially it looks like that tag is rather crappy, however there *may* be a need for it - it is a DOS (i.e. batch file) command that is still in use.

As an example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26620596/109702) relates to it.

So while it might not be a candidate for burnination that doesn't preclude a clean up - it appears that a vast majority of the questions using it shouldn't be.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make a [tag:batch-choice] (or some variant of that) tag? There's definitely some uses of [tag:choice] that deserve a special tag if they want it, but none so dominant that it merits a 'top-level' tag name like choice...

Comment: @GordonGustafson Na, it's common for tags to have multiple meanings, for most tags there's not much point in trying to differentiate them like that, it's better to just ensure the tag wiki is up to date and lists the options.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple meanings? If I'm an expert in one meaning of a certain tag I'd prefer questions that I know *nothing* about be tagged something else. Some variation in meaning is fine, but tags like [tag:merge] can mean so many things they essentially mean nothing.

Comment: @GordonGustafson So are you proposing that tags like `merge` are differentiated (i.e. by source control type) because you're only an expert in one of them? Or are you talking about how `sql-merge` and `merge` are (or should be) differentiated? You might have a valid point, but the 'problem' is as big or small as you want to make it.

Comment: `sql-merge` and `git-merge` is probably the example most similar to the situation with [tag:choice] (dropdown menus vs picking a language vs selecting an element from a collection etc.). I agree that `merge` could be dissected at different levels (I would support `git-merge` and `svn-merge` being separate tags as well, but that's more subjective and straying off-topic IMHO), but I think there's little ambiguity on how to split `choice`.